# PHP - function does not equal this echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a question about php (wordpress) I have a plugin(buddypress) with function bp_the_profile_field_name();

when i use

```
echo bp_the_profile_field_name();
```

It's return "Tags"

But..

```
if (bp_the_profile_field_name() == "Tags"){
    echo "Yes, it's working";
} else {
    echo "Oh no..";
        }
?>
```

its return "Oh no.."
When i try equal to string "Tags" dosent't match.
Why? Please help

Comment: please share the result of `var_dump(bp_the_profile_field_name());`

Comment: Does it *return* `"Tags"` or does it *echo* `"Tags"` and your additional `echo` statement is simply outputting nothing?  There's a significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

When googling to the source of the `bp_the_profile_field_name` function I found [this source](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_the_profile_field_name/):

```php
function bp_the_profile_field_name() {
    echo bp_get_the_profile_field_name();
}
```

Here we can see that the `the` function uses `echo` to **show** the value.

---

If you want to **get** the value to compare it with something else you'll need to use a other function which will return the value.

Below the mentioned page in the 'related' part this function is mentioned:

> ##### `bp_get_the_profile_field_name`
>
> > Returns the XProfile field name.

<sup>**Note** the `_get_` insteaf off `_the_`</sup>

Which returns a string. Source can be found [here](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_get_the_profile_field_name/).

So your code should become:

```php
if (bp_get_the_profile_field_name() == "Tags"){
    echo "Yes, it's working";
} else {
    echo "Oh no..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_the_profile_field_name/) bp_the_profile_field_name() echoes output.

If you want to compare the output of this function you need a return, not echo.

You have 2 options:

1. Use **bp_get_the_profile_field_name()** instead of **bp_the_profile_field_name()** in your if statement
2. Edit bp_the_profile_field_name() to output the result instead of echoing it.